# a URL that shows all user posts on a specific category

Tags: wordpress

is there a URL that shows all user posts on a specific category? basically, "/author/username/" can shows all the user's posts... is it possible on wordpress? I think it is there but I am not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. You can access your category posts like: /category/category_name/, or whatever you have configured on your permalinks. So you have to check your permalink configurations.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks